# The right, concise way to indicate current enrollment in multiple specific master's degree programs

Tags: meaning, differences, concision

EDIT: I originally titled this **"Master of Architecture student" or "Master of Architecture candidate"?** My apologies if the question was unclear, I couldn't think of a better title at the time, I hope this title is clearer. I'm not asking the definition of "candidate" vs. "student". Despite being a less common usage, "candidate" *is* sometimes used to describe students who are working towards a degree.

My question is about achieving the correct formal tone and concision for the context: a business card. A full sentence seems inappropriate in such a context, and I'm hoping to avoid acronyms because they are typically meaningless to those outside the discipline.

---

I'm looking for the right, concise way to indicate current enrollment in multiple specific master's degree program on a business card. I sometimes see "*candidate*" used for master's students, but it seems much more common for PhD students. Does "*candidate*" denote something more specific than "*student*" in this context?

Furthermore, if one were enrolled simultaneously in two master's programs, would it be appropriate to combine the two into "*Master of Architecture and City Planning student*" or "*Master of Architecture and Master of City Planning student*"?

Comment: None of the last. It sounds like you already graduated the first of the two. Architecture and City Planning student, which would give you a master when you grafuate. _I am currently studying for a M.Arch and a MCP_

Comment: Have you looked up "candidate" in a dictionary before asking here? "Candidate" does **not** mean "student", although a student may be a candidate. Try looking [here](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=candidate&title=21st) and [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/candidate?q=candidate) and [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/candidate).

Comment: @TrevorD Was that the downvote? I'm asking because despite the common definition, I've seen it used that way.

Comment: @TrevorD your third link notes one definition of candidate as: "a student studying for a degree"

Comment: Yes, I the time I wrote my previous comment your question said "Does "candidate" denote something more specific than "student" in this context?", which I read as suggesting that you thought "candidate" normally meant "student". So I answered that '"Candidate" does not [in general] mean "student", although [in certain circumstamces] a student may be a candidate.'

Comment: My record shows I didn't downvote. But I did consider it because of the guidance [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically: "If your question ... can probably be easily answered by looking it up ... Try a dictionary ... if your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, ... ***Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!***" If your original question had taken account of the dictionary definitions, it may have been clearer and easier to answer without misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *[candidate](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/candidate)* formally denotes "someone who is taking an examination," so saying someone is a master's candidate or a PhD candidate refers to a specific time in that student's academic career.

I had a co-worker who was pursuing master's degrees in mechanical engineering and in architecture, and phrased it just that way on his CV. So in your case:

> Currently pursuing master's degrees in architecture and in city
>   planning.

Or, more consisely:

> Pursuing [MArch](http://www.aias.org/website/article.asp?id=900) and MCP degrees.

If you want something that fits on a business card, I would go with "MArch/MCP 2015" with whatever date is appropriate for you.

Comment: Why is everything being downvoted with no explanation?

Comment: Thanks @Gnawme, that's helpful but I'm hoping for something short enough that it would be appropriate for a business card _in addition to_ a CV. A sentence seems like too much.

Comment: I've added a suggestion that would fit on a business card to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Gnawme. I'll wait a while to see if anyone can think of a good way to eliminate the acronyms. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: They're standard [AIAS](http://www.aias.org/website/article.asp?id=900) abbreviations. If you have room on the card, "Master of Architecture/Master of City Planning 2015" would work.

Answer (score 4):

In my Ph.D. program, you didn't use *candidate* until you had passed your coursework and prelim (leaving you with just your research and dissertation). A *candidate* was therefore an indication that you were quite far along in your studies.  We used *student* for the ones still taking classes.

So on a business card, put "Master's student" if you have not yet completed your required coursework and "Master's candidate" if you are writing your thesis and preparing to defend.

Unless a single degree will be conferred, you should use Master of Architecture and Master of City Planning to make sure that it is clear that these are two separate credentials.

> Benjamin Golder
>   Master's candidate
>   Architecture
>   City Planning

Comment: +1 great explanation of the possible issues with using "candidate", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was advised by a neighbour, (who is on her 5th/6th degree or something), that the appropriate usage would be M.A.(C)  or PH.D.(C).  or M.B.A.(C) or ____(C). The bracketed "C" stands for "Candidate."

For a business card I like the short crispness of it. For a CV, a signature under your email, or any other bio, I would elaborate with phrasing that confirms that your degree is 'in progress', there are some great ways of doing so in other notes in this thread. Personally, I would not use (C) for a Bachelor's degree, and would restrict it to advanced degrees.