# Is a student studying towards <a degree> "a <a degree> student"?

Tags: academia, honorifics

For example, I assume a "M.Sc. student" would be a person who hasn't yet obtained a Masters degree?

I'm almost sure this is what it means, but not 100% sure, so I'd like to have it verified.

(I'm sorry if this should got to ELL.)

Comment: Have you Googled "BA student"?

Comment: You could perhaps use "candidate" in place of "student".

Comment: @ralph.m That may depend on the program. See e.g. *[The right, concise way to indicate current enrollment in multiple specific master's degree programs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117517)*.

Comment: Well that link kind of answers the question, and others!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The right, concise way to indicate current enrollment in multiple specific master's degree programs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117517/the-right-concise-way-to-indicate-current-enrollment-in-multiple-specific-maste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "masters" student would mean a student studying towards a masters degree.

It's just a shorthand (used mainly in first person I think)

> I am a masters student

vs

> I am a student studying towards a masters degree

Those who already have degrees would typically say

> I have a/my masters [degree]

note: It's rather hard to find concrete rules about colloquialisms but Wikipedia, for example, follows the rules I stated: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgraduate_education

Comment: This may well be true, but unsupported answers are generally not well received on ELU.

Comment: It's rather hard to find concrete rules about colloqualisims but Wikipedia, for example, follows the rules I stated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgraduate_educatio n

Comment: Then why not put that in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

*For example, I assume a "M.Sc. student" would be a person who hasn't yet obtained a Masters degree?*

Firstly, it would be ***an*** M Sc student, and unless it was important to distinguish, most often people would just say "a masters student". And yes - an M Sc student would be one studying for it, rather than one who has obtained it.